# type requirments when copying columns from one table to another

Tags: mysql

So I have a Addresses table and a Contacts table.

I am trying to copy contact_id[int], address_street[varchar(256)], address_city[varchar(80)], address_state[varchar(20)], address_country[varchar(5)] from Contacts into these columns, contact_id[int], street1[varchar(128)], city[varchar(128)], state[varchar(128)], country[varchar(128)] from Addresses.

The command I am using through a java interface is `insert into Addresses ( contact_id, street1, city, state, country) select id, address_street, address_city, address_state, address_country from Contacts)`. Is the error coming from a mismatch of varchar sizes because I dont think the mysql statement is wrong according to https://catdevblog.nickbair.net/2012/04/05/mysql-copying-column-data-between-tables/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `)` in your posted query.

Other than that, truncation of values is automatic and will only generate a warning, unless [strict mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html) is enabled, then you will get an error.

Comment: Lol, that was the problem. I thought it was something much more complicated.